# Spring Integration logging error channel (slf4j + logback)

Tags: spring, logging, spring-integration, slf4j, logback

I am using Spring integration with this configuration:

```
@Bean MessageChannel errorChannel(){
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}

@MessagingGateway(name = "gatewayInbound", 
defaultRequestChannel="farsRequestChannel", errorChannel="errorChannel"){
}
```

With this configuration, I am avoiding showing messages but I want to create a basic log such as LOGGER.error().

Additionally, I am working with SLFJ and logbak. Thus, the perfect scenario will be integrate this error message with similar configuration in my logback XML. For this reason:

- Can I use logback to log Spring integration errorChannel LOGS?
- Can I show the error sent to an errorChannel?
- Can I personalize this error with this similar expression in logback? If I use, LoggingHandler, I see the complete stack trace and I want to customize this message.

  [%-5level] - %d{dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss} - [%file:%line] - %msg%n

Comment: Spring integration already provides a [`logging-channel-adapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#logging-channel-adapter) for that. This uses commons-logging so you can basically do whatever you want...

Comment: Ok, as my example shows, I am working with annotated spring integration and logback. Could you give some references o guidelines about this example? I am not working with commons-logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="myErrorChannel")
public MessageHandler myLogger() {
    return new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            ErrorMessage em = (ErrorMessage) message;
            String errorMessage = em.getPayload().getMessage();

            // log it

            throw (MessagingException) em.getPayload();
        }
    };
}
```

If you don't want the exception to be propagated, you can just consume it, but you need to set `defaultReplyTimeout=0` on the gateway (and `null` will be returned).

or

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="myErrorChannel")
public MessageHandler loggingHandler() {
    LoggingHandler loggingHandler = new LoggingHandler("ERROR");
    loggingHandler.setExpression("payload.message");
    return loggingHandler;
}
```

(the error will be consumed in this case).

Comment: Thank you Gary. B) is exactly what I was looking for. For me, the most useful thing of your answer is:  loggingHandler.setExpression("payload.message"). Because I was working with something similar but it returned LoggingHandler instead MessageHandler